Passing data protection to a custom attribute
Good day everyone,
I am building a Custom Authorization handler. Within the handler, there is a context value that I need to handle and it is available within my custom handler. However, this value is data protected via IDataProtector.
This works fine throughout my application, but I'm having trouble adding this capability to my custom handler, thus I am unable to Unprotect my context value.
Here is how I am implementing data protection in my controllers:
public class FlowerController(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
{
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector =  dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Petunias");
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            string unprotectedString;
            try
            {
                unprotectedString = _dataProtector.Unprotect(id);


            }
        }
    }
}

The above code works without a hitch.
Here is what I built for CustomAuthorization(basic version - without data protection features):
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _roleName;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string RoleName)
    {
        _roleName = RoleName; 
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User; //get user
        var entityID = context.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString(); // get id

        //do something
        var isAuthorized = true;
        
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            return;
        }
    }
}

The implementation within my controller:
[CustomAuthorize(RoleName: "Gardener, Pruner")]
public IActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    // controller stuff
}

Now, here is my attempt at implementing a CustomAuthorization handler that employs Dataprotection:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _roleName;
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;


    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string RoleName, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
    {
        _roleName = RoleName;
        _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Petunias");   
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User; //get user
        var entityID = context.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString(); //get id (protected)
        var unprotectedText = _dataProtector.Unprotect(entityID); //unprotect id

        //do something
        var isAuthorized = true;

        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            return;
        }
    }
}

In my controller, there is an error being thrown by the custom authorization tag that an argument is missing (There is no argument given that corresponds
to the required parameter 'dataProtectionProvider' of 'CustomAuthorizeAttribute.CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string, IDataProtectionProvider)'
How can I inject the Data Protection service into my handler without having to pass the argument from my Controller? Or, if I have to, the solution to my error message.
Thanks,
HM

I expected to be able to pass the dataprotector from my custom attribute in my controller, but it appears that that is not possible. I need to inject data protection in my custom attribute definition. I don't know how to do this.


Base don your shared code snippet and description,
to integrate data protection into a custom authorization attribute in ASP.NET Core, you can't directly inject IDataProtectionProvider due to attribute constraints on dependency injection. Instead, utilize a factory pattern: create a DataProtectionProviderFactory to resolve IDataProtectionProvider, and inject it into the CustomAuthorizeAttribute. Within the attribute, use the factory to obtain an IDataProtector. This approach separates concerns, allowing for proper dependency injection and maintaining the attribute's functionality.
